# Перевод текста с помощью translate.google

Tags: xcode, objective-c, mac

Собираюсь реализовать программу для перевода текста с немецкого на русский, с использованием сервиса Google. Может кто в курсе каких-то заготовок? Как правильно начинать в этом направлении? Буду благодарен за любую информацию.

Comment: Гугловский переводчик? Хм.

     Три танкиста три веселых друга
     Drei Tanker drei Homosexuell Freund

Три танкиста стали тремя танкерами, да ещё и голубыми...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Отсюда](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/libraries?hl=ru) и начинайте. Не забудьте обратить внимание на секцию Pricing. Ну и если это коммерческая разработка и это основной функционал приложения, то обратите внимание на то что программ с таким функционалом уже довольно много

Comment: Я сразу и не понял что такое "Pricing". Оказывается сервис платный.